# Mostrar alert ao selecionar select

Tags: php, javascript, html5, mysqli, select

Tenho o seguinte codigo

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, nome, situacao FROM clientes ORDER BY nome") or print mysql_error()

<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente">
   <option value="Selecione o Cliente"> Selecione o Cliente</option>
        <?php                           
          while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $dados['id'] ?>">
        <?php 
        if ($dados['situacao']==1) {
          $dados['situacao']='Em dia';
        } else {
          $dados['situacao']='Devendo';
        }
          echo $dados['nome'] . ' -> '. $dados['situacao']; 
        ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Precisava que com a mesma verificacao do campo `situacao`, mostrasse um alert mostrando que o cliente esta devendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode verificar se na string dentro da sua `option` que foi selecionada tiver a palavra `Devendo`, ele mostra o alert.

Se utilizar jQuery é uma opção:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){ 
  if( $(this).find('option:selected').text().indexOf('Devendo') > 0) {
    alert('O Cliente esta devendo!');
  }
});
```

Caso não queira utilizar jQuery, abaixo segue só em Javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('cliente');

element.addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var curSelected = this.querySelectorAll('option:checked')[0];
    if(curSelected && curSelected.innerHTML.indexOf('Devendo') > 0){
        alert ("O Cliente está devendo!");
    }
}
```

Você pode verificar funcionando conforme abaixo:

```js
/* utilizando jQuery */
$('select').on('change', function(){ 
  if( $(this).find('option:selected').text().indexOf('Devendo') > 0) {
    alert('O Cliente esta devendo pelo jQuery!');
  }
});



/* utilizando apenas Javascript */
var element = document.getElementById('cliente');

element.addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var curSelected = this.querySelectorAll('option:checked')[0];
    if(curSelected && curSelected.innerHTML.indexOf('Devendo') > 0){
     alert ("O Cliente está devendo pelo Javascript!");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente">
   <option value="Selecione o Cliente"> Selecione o Cliente</option>
   <option value="Selecione o Cliente2"> Selecione o Cliente 2 Devendo</option>
   <option value="Selecione o Cliente3"> Selecione Devendoo Cliente</option>
   <option value="Selecione o Cliente4"> Selecione o Cliente</option>
</select>
```

Comment: O OP comentou que estava usando _jQuery_? Se não, é temerário assumir que ele incluiria a biblioteca só por causa de um `alert()`...

Comment: Essa é uma opção ... ele tb não disse que não poderia usar jQuery... de qq forma da pra fazer do mesmo jeito usando só JavaScript...

Comment: putz tentei aqui nao funcionou

Comment: @wribeiro posta o resultado final do seu html... por favor - sem o PHP

Comment: Em vez de dar um *downvote* na resposta, é melhor pedir pro **OP** melhorar a pergunta. Porque para um `alert` é só fazer: `<script type="text/javascript"> var situacao = "<?= $dados['situacao'] ?>"; if(situacao == "Devendo"){ alert("Devendo!");} </script>`

Comment: Galera usando o jquery consegui, porém deu outro problema, o alert mostra 3 ou 4 vezes seguido, como se tivesse no loop tambem

Comment: Na verdade ele está no loop... vc precisa do alert quando carrega? Ou quando vc clica nas opções que tem Devendo?

Comment: @andrepaulo ele deve mostrar o alert, quando clico no cliente devendo, e atualmente esta acontecendo isso, se clicar em um cliente ok, nao mostra o alert, no devendo ocorre 2,3x nao tem um numero certo

Comment: Vc chegou a fazer do jeito que eu propus na resposta?

Comment: @andrepaulo usei o seguinte $('select').on('change', function(){ 
  if( $(this).find('option:selected').text().indexOf('Devendo') > 0) {
    alert('O Cliente esta devendo pelo jQuery!');
  }
});

Comment: Vc colocou isso no final da sua página?

Comment: @andrepaulo, exato criei uma funcao, e no select eu chamo ela com o onchange

Comment: acho que identifiquei aqui, o que ocorre é o seguinte, quando seleciona a primeira vez o cliente 'devendo' ele mostra 1x o alert, se eu clicar novamente em outro ele adiciona +1, entao mostra 2x e assim vai, sempre adicionando 1

Comment: Aí que está o ponto... vc não precisa criar função e nem chamar no onchange.. isso já está sendo feito... basta colocar o código no final da página... que ele vai fazer exatamente isso pra vc.. vou explicar melhor na resposta..

Comment: ah, entendi deu certo agora

Comment: boa! fico Feliz que a resposta te ajudou